# Japan tourist visa: Surname spelt differently on my income tax return

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, japan, tourist-visas

I'm an Indian national planning to apply for a Japan tourist visa.

However, the surname on my income tax return (Dutta) is different from the surname on my passport and all other documents (Dutt). Since an ITR document is compulsory for a Japan tourist visa, can this discrepancy lead to my tourist visa being rejected?

Comment: If your official name is "Dutt", can you ask the authorities to issue a new ITR with the correct name?

Answer (score 7):

No one can answer for sure, as we are not with the Japanese consulate. You can always ask them about this kind of questions though, and I see no reason why they won't answer.

But there's always a safe option: if that's indeed your document, a notary would be able to produce a notarization document which certifies that the income tax return and the passport indeed belongs to the same person.